# azure-devops-node-api: Trouble calling queryByWiql() function with WIQL argument

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, tags, wiql

first question here.
I am developing a program that needs to query my azure devops organization and return a list of work item references filtered by System.Tag and System.TeamProject.

To do this, I decided to use azure-devops-node-api's queryByWiql() function in the following way:

```
//create a new WIQL object of data we want
const query: string = "SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = [" + this.globals.API_PROJECT + "] AND [System.Tags] Contains [" + tag + "]";
console.log(query);

//create a new TeamContext object so the query knows where to look
const projectId = this.globals.API_PROJECT;

//ping ADO with this query
const result: WorkItemTrackingInterfaces.WorkItemQueryResult = await WorkItemApiObject.queryByWiql({query: query}, {project: projectId}); //WHY DOESNT THIS WORKKKKKK
```

where 'this.globals.API_PROJECT' is a string referencing the project name and 'tag' is a string of the name of the tag I want to query work-items by.

The thing is, when I call queryByWiql() with parameters 'this.globals.API_PROJECT' = projectName and 'tag' = tagName (just random parameters: I get the same error message no matter what), I get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () from dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/wiql:1
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: TF51005: The query references a field that does not exist. The error is caused by «projectName».
at RestClient.<anonymous> (RestClient.js:202)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (RestClient.js:6)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
at Object.onInvoke (core.js:27148)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:363)
at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:123)
at zone-evergreen.js:857
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27136)
at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
at zone-evergreen.js:705
at rejected (tslib.es6.js:72)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
at Object.onInvoke (core.js:27148)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:363)
at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:123)
at zone-evergreen.js:857
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27136)
```

The problem is, I know for a fact that projectName and tagName exist in the project and organization I am querying. I also know that I am using the correct references to these fields "System.Tag" and "System.TeamProject" since I went and checked my project for these specifically.

All I want to do is get a type WorkItemTrackingInterfaces.WorkItemQueryResult from this call. Please help! Thank you for your time.

EDIT1: Added Resource Load Fail error message since that also happens.

Comment: Yes I have. The brackets are necessary since there are some projects and tags in my organization that use space and special characters and the brackets let the API know that these characters are still part of the tag/project name. Anyways, even without the brackets the error is still the same. Good question though

Comment: UPDATE: I'm wrong. Answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
I fixed it. I feel so silly for not doing this. Turns out I misunderstood what brackets [] are supposed to be in WIQL-- They are only supposed to represent fields. To indicate strings with spaces and special characters, surround the string with '', like the following:

```
const query: string = "SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = '" + this.globals.API_PROJECT + "' AND [System.Tags] Contains '" + tag + "'";
```

...yeah, turns out it was a syntax error all along. I feel so silly LOL. I spent so much time on this haha

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend maybe you try out the marketplace extension, [Wiql Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor).  It let's you play around with the syntax and query results.

I just mocked up something and as I kind of expected, wrapping with the [ ] appears to be causing it to think you are referencing a field instead of a literal.  At least the error message looks identical.

[image]

And without..

[image]

Comment: You are exactly right. I figured this out (well, my boss figured it out) just as you posted. Thank you anyway! I appreciate it.